# Element not found when deploying to phone

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm unable to deploy UWP apps to my phone running Window 10 Mobile Insider Preview 10512. When I attempt to deploy in VS 2015, I'm getting the error:

> Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Element not found. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070490)

The phone is developer unlocked. I'm able to deploy UWP apps to my local machine, simulators and phone emulators. Any ideas? Is it the phone build?

Comment: what about test on another unlocked WP device?

Comment: Don't have another at the moment, but will try if/when I can get my hands on another. I'm going to try on another machine to rule out my VS installation.

Comment: Same problem for me. Any news ?

Comment: nothing yet. I was hoping the new preview build would fix it, but my device isn't seeing it yet.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. It was working correctly until I updated my phone to build 10536.1004. I tried uninstalling the previous version of my app and restarting the phone, but nothing worked. I can deploy the same app to my local computer though.

Comment: same issue here. with device version 10.0.10586

Answer (score 0):

This problem is connected with build 10512 and UWP platform version installed.
Please try to update to Window 10 Mobile Insider Preview 10586.
I had the same problem and after the update everything is fine.
I also recommend to always check if the currently installed UWP version is the newest one.